# Examine the below time-series plot of data. With reference to the graph, justify the chosen method for the analysis that has been started on the table

Tags: forecasting, trend, moving-average, decomposition

[image: graph][image: Table]

Please can I be provided with a good answer/justification for the question? I think there is one method and it is moving average? I am not sure though.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Hi thanks. This is self study. What I initially thought was that this is some form of classical decomposition, but now I believe it’s moving average? That’s what I’ve deduced from the table. But not sure how to use the graph for reference